# C++ Windows font size question

Tags: c++, windows, fonts, size, edit

First i'm using the windows api.

So I have an edit control, that needs to be able to fit 22 characters max.
Currently only 12 fit with the font I'd like to use.

Is there any way to resize the font well the user is typing to allow for more text to fit without creating a bunch of fonts?

Comment: Short answer is no. Long answer is: Creating a bunch of fonts shouldn't be a problem. You should probably be more concerned about scaling the font.

Comment: Why not either just set a font size that allows 22 characters (or resize the edit control) up front? No special code required.

Comment: Resizing the font would be quite visually jarring and would remove the visual how-much-do-I-need-to-type cue

Comment: And note that Windows cannot resize fonts continuously, so you will get a rather painful visual experience.

Comment: Do you mean 22 i's or 22 w's?  If you use a non-proportional font (all characters the same width like Courier) you could use a static width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could.  Implement a message handler for EN_CHANGE so you know the text was changed.  Use GetWindowDC and DrawTextEx with the DT_CALCRECT and DT_EDITCONTROL flags to measure the size of the text. Send WM_SETFONT to change the font for the control if it doesn't fit and repeat.

The user being pleased with the end result is however very unlikely.